# Setting custom CA cert with cloud_proxy_sql

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, self-signed-certificate, cloud-sql-proxy, root-certificate

I'm trying to use GCP's `cloud_proxy_sql` via one of our proxy server with custom CA signed certificates. I tried setting the cert using the config `custom_ca_certs_file` of `gcloud config`. Also double checked if the ca cert is set, using the command `gcloud config list`.

In spite of that, getting the below error in `cloud_proxy_sql` when trying to connect my SQL client via `cloud_proxy_sql`.

> 2020/08/19 11:37:36 Listening on 0.0.0.0:<My local port> for <Instance_connnection_name>
>
> 2020/08/19 11:37:36 Ready for new connections 2020/08/19 11:39:11 New connection for "<Instance_connnection_name>"
>
> 2020/08/19 11:39:12 couldn't connect to "<Instance_connnection_name>": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
>
> 2020/08/19 11:40:08 Received TERM signal. Waiting up to 0s before terminating.

It seems like `cloud_proxy_sql` is not respecting the CA cert in `gcloud` config. How to configure the cert for `cloud_proxy_sql`?

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that your client is not able to trust the certificate of https://www.googleapis.com.

This can happen due to:

- The client does not know what root certificates to trust.
- The outbound traffic is using a proxy server that is using a different, untrusted, certificate.
- The 'ca-certificates.crt' file to be on /etc/ssl/certs, which is one of the locations some languages look for certificates.

I found more about this here:
[Failure to connect to proxy "Certificate signed by unknown authority"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52712907/failure-to-connect-to-proxy-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I understand the problem. I would to like to pass ca cert to cloud_sql_proxy. Rephrased the questions to make it explicit.

Comment: This is the closest I could find on GCP Documentation:

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/diagnose-issues#occasional_connection_failures